# Turtlebot 3 - Setup

Tags: turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all.

I have just assembled the turtlebot 3 and installation of ROS on respective platforms and I am really excited with what I can do with this!

1. I can't get OpenCR to move the DYAMIXEL when holding SW 1 and SW2.
2. I need to connect a few sensors to Raspberry Pi 3 and to transmit those sensor data to a master computer. Would it be possible to do that through ROS or do I have to try it out with Python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279811/turtlebot-3---setup/) by [Bbybo93](https://answers.ros.org/users/33285/bbybo93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

1.
The openCR should already be pre-configured. In the documentation (http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/overview/#turtlebot3) keep pressing SW1 or SW2 for at least 3-4 seconds. If it is still not working, can you check the status of the various LEDs?

2.
You will need to get the data from the sensor (by using any libraries you need) and then create a ROS Node to publish them to your main server.

---

Originally posted by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) with karma: 527 on 2018-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1